# Is there an object (like airplane) between me and moon

Tags: geometry

I found a cool picture of airplane passing by our moon. Link: [Airplane & moon](https://scontent-a-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/t31.0-8/10630626_10152371721006139_6488688245555223545_o.jpg). What I was thinking is an application what tells if there is an object between my position and moon.

**What we know is**:

1. My position (Latitude, Longitude, Altitude [from sea level])
2. Current precise time.
3. Airplane(s) position (Latitude, Longitude, Altitude[from sea level])

So I guess that first problem to solve is moon theoretical position (Lat,Lon,Alt), or is there a better way to start solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as a [solid angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) problem. For a given position of the moon in spherical coordinates (which is a function of the time of day), you have a solid angle between you and it, and you look at everything inside that cone.

Hope that helps.